# How to correct this missing numbering series in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I deleted a 45th row, but numbering system gone wrong like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeYFy.jpg)

Now I need correct from 45th row. please help me.

Google only shows results of [where to find missing numbers](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1054-excel-identify-missing-numbers-sequence.html)

but never shows me results of how to correct those missing numbers.

Comment: Have you tried `Ctrl+Z` ?

Answer (score 0):

Enter the formula in A58 and drop down:

```
=ROUND(ROW(A45)/1,0)&"."
```

[image]